# VanDerPol ODE "blows up" around parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working with implementing an ODE solver for the Van Der Pol system of ODES in Julia programming language. Here is my implementation:

```
function van_der_pol_euler(delta, y0, μ)
    # Define the system of ODEs
    f(y, μ) = [y[2], 10 * (1 - y[1]^2) * y[2] - y[1]]

    # Calculate the new values of y using Euler's method
    y1 = y0 + delta .* f(y0, μ)

    return y1
end
```

The IVs I passed were delta = 2.5, y0 = [2, 0] and μ = 10.0. The output I'm getting is:

```
[2.0, -5.0]
[-10.5, 365.0]
[902.0, -996515.0]
[-2.4903855e6, 2.0269188839855e13]
[5.0672969609252e13, -3.1427478331054e27]
[-7.856869582763449e27, 2.0174475684912193e56]
[5.043618921228049e56, -3.113446116420647e113]
[-7.783615291051618e113, 1.9800032048532777e228]
[4.950008012133194e228, -Inf]
[-Inf, NaN]
[NaN, NaN]
```

I'm fairly new to the Van Der Pol system of ODEs so any help in explaining this behavior would be appreciated.